# What does "no error" mean when writing to a file in Lua?

Tags: file, lua, io, mpv

I am writing a script to add one line in a .txt per video while using MPV.

However, I am getting a weird error on line 68 with the for loop.
It merely tells me: no error. If I add an error parameter to file:write(message, error), it gives me another error message, stating: `bad argument #2 to 'write' (string expected, got function)`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function on_file_end(event)
    if not paused then totaltime = totaltime + os.clock() - lasttime end
    local message = (totaltime .. "s, " .. timeloaded .. ", " .. filename)
    local lines = {}
    local file = io.open(logpath, "r+")
    if file_exists(logpath) then
        for l in file:lines() do 
            if not l:find(message, 1, true) then
                lines[#lines+1] = 1
                file:write(message)
            end
        end
        file:close()
    end
end
```

Comment: please provide the full error message. why do you think it is an error if it says "no error"?  which line is 68? `for l in file:lines() do` ?

Comment: That's right. It does not say anything else. I have checked the log.

Comment: again: why do you think it is an error when it says "no error"?

Answer (score 1):

> bad argument #2 to 'write' (string expected, got function)

`error` is not an "error parameter" it is a global function that allows to raise your own errors in Lua.

See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-error

Comment: I see, but how do I implement it in my script or fix this weird thing with "no error"?

Comment: I don't understand why I am receiving this oddity. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28716224/153213914-20747a32-bd9f-45d3-97fb-9b9001d59d16.png. Here is the image with all the logs related to the script - temptimelogger. I hope its helpful

Comment: I don't see any "no error" on this screenshot. it's just the error that I helped you with in your last question

Comment: Sorry about that.  I created a new StackOverflow post and would appreciate your input if you can see a solution for me now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051860/my-code-to-write-to-a-file-does-not-work-file-remains-empty